# Did Allah accept my Shahadah given my doubts?

Tags: shahada, doubts, waswasa, depression

This is going to be a bit long so please, bear with me.

I am a 21 year old university student. I was born and raised a muslim. I have visited Saudi Arabia and performed Umrah many times and Hajj twice. I have always been proud to be a muslim. My Imaan has always been strong. Whenever I had doubts about Islam, it was easy for me to believe that they are just whispers of shaytaan. It was easy for me to ignore them. But that was until a few months ago.

A few months ago, I read something online about Muhammad (s.a.w.) which had disastrous effects on my Imaan. I'm not gonna say what I read because it might affect the Imaan of other muslims reading this. But after I read it, I started asking myself "What if I'm following the wrong religion? What if Islam is not the truth?" I prayed to Allah everyday to make these thoughts go away. But Allah wasn't answering. I couldn't ignore these thoughts as waswas from shaytaan.

For the first time in my life, I started suffering from depression. I wanted to end my life but I was too scared to do that because of what Islam teaches about suicide. I decided to talk to my parents about this issue. They told me:"Do not look for proof or reasoning for any religion. If there existed a reason/proof for any religion, everyone in the world would be following that religion. Instead, you should follow Islam blindly and assume that all doubts are whispers of shaytaan. You just have to take a leap of faith and "believe without reasoning"". I also talked to my younger brother about this issue and he gave me the exact same answer.

At first I thought that advice was absurd. How can anyone simply "believe without reasoning"? I didn't follow their advice. I decided to keep looking for reasons to believe Islam is the truth.

At first, I found a good reason to follow Islam. So I went with it. And I started to feel a lot better. But after a few weeks, I could no longer believe in that reason. In other words, I found a reason NOT to believe in that reason. So the doubts started to come back. The depression came back. I started crying to my parents again and they gave me the same reply as before: "Believe without reason. All doubts are whispers of shaytaan"

A few days later, I found another reason to believe in Islam. And it was going quite well for a couple of days. But once again, I started to have doubts about those reasons as well. Once again, I started crying to my parents and once again, they gave me the same advice: "Believe without reason"

So what did I do after that? I gave up. I finally took my parents' advice. Why? Because they were right. If I ever find a reason to follow a particular religion, then eventually, I will come across something that will give me doubts about that reason. Since I was born and raised muslim, I still had a little bit of Imaan left inside of me. So with that little bit of Imaan, I proclaimed the Shahadah again.

For a couple of weeks, I was feeling a lot better. Everytime I had doubts, I just told myself "These are whispers of shaytaan".

But suddenly, I remembered something. I remembered that if someone says Shahadah, he/she must do it with certainty. And only Allah knows what's in your heart. So I thought to myself: "Since some of the doubts were still there, I didn't recite Shahadah with a pure heart. But with the little bit of Imaan I had left inside of me, I did the best I could. So did Allah accept my Shahadah?"

So brothers and sisters, I'm not asking you to help me believe in Islam because any reason you find can and will be refuted by someone. I want to follow Islam blindly. **But my question to you is: Did Allah accept my Shahadah?** Despite all my doubts, if I tell myself "I will follow Islam no matter what. All doubts are "whispers of Shaytaan" it just means that my heart is impure. My heart doesn't entirely believe in Islam but there is still a little bit of Imaan left inside of me. I don't care about other religions. This is the religion I want to believe. But would my Shahadah be accepted?

I still pray 5 times a day but I'm afraid Allah is not accepting my Salah because I said Shahadah with an impure heart. I keep thinking "What if the doubts in my mind are not waswaas of shaytaan? What if it's all me?"

Answer (score 0):

Your parents are wrong I'm afraid, because your parents response is no different than saying that you are a Muslim because you where born into a Muslim family or country.

Allah and his Prophets/Messengers repetitively warn against blindly following the footsteps of our parents and ancestors:

> Surah Anbiyaa verse 52-54: Recall to mind the occasion when Ibrahim
>   said to his father and his people, What are these images to which you
>   are so devoted? They replied, We found our forefathers worshipping
>   them. Ibrahim said, You have gone astray and so had your forefathers
>   manifestly deviated from the Right Way.
>
> Surah Al Baqarah 2:170 But when they are told, "Follow what God has
>   bestowed from on high," some answer, "Nay, we shall follow [only] that
>   which we found our forefathers believing in and doing." Why, even if
>   their forefathers did not use their reason at all, and were devoid of
>   all guidance?

This is an unjust and ridiculous concept, this means that all relegions are right because most other religions and missionaries also use the same reasoning "You are just meant to believe". GOD/Allah has provided us with evidence to proof to us his existence otherwise how do we know that our messengers where not preachers of man made religions?

> And if We had destroyed them with a punishment before him, they would
>   have said, "Our Lord, why did You not send to us a messenger so we
>   could have followed Your verses before we were humiliated and
>   disgraced?"

If we are not supposed to reason then why does Allah encourage us to contemplate and ask questions?

> Then (do) not they ponder (on) the Quran? And if it had (been) from
>   other than Allah, surely they (would have) found in it much
>   contradiction. [4:82]

It is okay to have doubts, just you've mentioned that we often have doubts then at some point in time later these doubts

> The Messenger of Allaah -sallalahu alayhe wa sallam – used to say: “O
>   Turner of the hearts, keep my heart firm upon your religion” So I
>   (Anas) said: O Messenger of Allaah, we have believed in you and
>   believed in everything you have been sent with, so are you afraid for
>   us? He said: “Yes.  Indeed the hearts are between two fingers from the
>   fingers of Allaah – He turns them however He wills”

Did Allah accept your supplication? Only Allah knows the answer to this just because you didn't receive the answer you wanted it does not mean that Allah did not respond:

> And when My servants ask you, [O Muhammad], concerning Me - indeed I
>   am near. I respond to the invocation of the supplicant when he calls
>   upon Me. So let them respond to Me [by obedience] and believe in Me
>   that they may be [rightly] guided. [2:186]

In conclusion, No don't follow Islam blindly and don't base your belief on the wrong reasons rather study Islam, study Islam and bear in mind that there are things that we might never know the answer to rather we have already established that Allah/GOD exists and we are suppoused to submit to God and follow his orders

> We will show them Our signs in the horizons and within themselves
>   until it becomes clear to them that it is the truth. But is it not
>   sufficient concerning your Lord that He is, over all things, a
>   Witness? [41:53]

Believing in the unseen is part of belief any ways:

> With Him are the keys of the unseen (ghayb). No one knows them other
>   than Him. He knows what is in land and sea. No leaf falls but He knows
>   it; nor there is a grain in the darkness of the earth or a green or
>   dry thing but in a manifest Book. (6.59)

For example: why did GOD make us walk on two feet instead of four?

Although Islam teaches us to respect our parents and honour them it does not mean that they are ultimately right and know neither does sheikh Google:

> "And We did not send before you except men whom We inspired to. So ask
>   the People of the Reminder (Ahl-Azzikr / أهل الذكر ) if you do not
>   know." (Qur'an 21:6-7)

Stay away from Islamaphobe sites, to some visiting those sites may strengthen their believe while to others it may strengthen their dis-believe, always go to the source to seek knowledge.

May GOD guide us all Inshallah.

Comment: I have no doubts that Allah exists. I have no doubts that Isa (a.s.) was a prophet. My doubt mostly surrounds Muhammad's (pbuh) prophethood. I have a hard time convincing myself that Muhammad (pbuh) was a prophet. That's the doubt I'm trying to clear

Comment: @curiosity What research or studies have you done so far to investigate his prophet hood?

Comment: What are those doubts any ways, can you please ask them in separate question? If we don't know we can't really help you!

Comment: I opened a chatroom. I would like you to chat with me there. "Doubts about Islam"

Comment: @curiosity I think Aboudi has a point. Would you like to explain what exactly makes you doubt?

Comment: @Kilise "When I found out that Isa (a.s.) never claimed divinity in the bible, I started asking myself: "What if the bible is the last revelation and Isa is the last prophet?"
Because if bible doesn't say Isa is the last prophet, then technically, bible's not wrong" quoted from his/her response in the chat room

Comment: @Aboudi to be honest I don't understand the reasoning at all. How would that found that isa wasn't divine lead to him being the last prophet? There are many prophet's not being divine. Shouldn't they all then be the last prophet?

Comment: @Kilise, So I am not the only one not understanding that point!  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47253/doubts-about-islam